# Someone has more "than me" or "than I"?

Tags: grammar

Example: He has better dance moves than I/me.

This I/me stuff is sometimes pretty confusing... :(

I think I would say "I" because you could say "He has better dance moves than I *have*".

But I'm not sure about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

> "He has better dance moves than I."

is correct for just the reason you included in your question. However, in normal speech, this "correct" usage can be taken too far and sound awkward or affected.

To quote a source I no longer remember, if you are looking at an album of old photographs with a friend, it would sound awfully odd if you pointed to a picture of yourself and said,

> "Look! That's I! That's I!"

even though you would technically be correct. Use common sense and you will be OK. You already understand the principle correctly.

Comment: @Rompey I have heard many times people say "so do I" in response to "I love you" or "I hate you" or whatever. It's not always "Me, too". Sometimes "You, too" is broadly used and it all depends on context.